# Rails application does not automatically update changes in CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, rubymine

I have a Rails 6.0.3.4 application. If i make a change to CSS and refresh the browser, the change is not shown. Changes to CSS only work when i delete the rails temp folder using:

```
$ rails tmp:clear
```

I am currently using rubymine. Every other project works perfectly except this specific project.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',                      '6.0.3.4'
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'
gem 'bcrypt',                     '3.1.13'
gem 'faker',                      '2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate',              '3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '3.4.1'
gem 'puma',                       '4.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '1.4.6', require: false
gem 'pg',                         '1.2.3'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',  '11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '4.0.2'
  gem 'listen',                '3.2.1'
  gem 'spring',                '2.1.1'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.32.2'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.3.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '1.2.3'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.46.0', require: false
end
```

This is my Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.4)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.4)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.4)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.3.4)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.4)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    active_storage_validations (0.8.9)
      rails (>= 5.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
    activerecord (6.0.3.4)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
    activestorage (6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.4)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.4)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.3.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (10.0.3.0)
      execjs
    aws-eventstream (1.1.0)
    aws-partitions (1.402.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.110.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.239.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.39.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.109.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.46.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.61.1)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.2.2)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.6)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sassc (>= 2.0.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (1.0.0)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.32.2)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.7)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faker (2.11.0)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
    ffi (1.13.1)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    guard (2.16.2)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-minitest (2.4.6)
      guard-compat (~> 1.2)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    i18n (1.8.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.9.3)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.13, < 3)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    listen (3.2.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.8.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.2.8)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.5)
    mini_magick (4.9.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    minitest-reporters (1.3.8)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    msgpack (1.3.3)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nio4r (2.5.4)
    nokogiri (1.10.10)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    notiffany (0.1.3)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (1.2.3)
    pry (0.13.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (4.3.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.3.4)
      actioncable (= 6.0.3.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.3.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      actiontext (= 6.0.3.4)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.4)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.4)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.4)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.4)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.3.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.x)
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.x)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.x)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.3.4)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.4)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.8.2)
    ruby-progressbar (1.10.1)
    ruby-vips (2.0.17)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.8)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    web-console (4.0.2)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.3.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    will_paginate (3.3.0)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_storage_validations (= 0.8.9)
  aws-sdk-s3 (= 1.46.0)
  bcrypt (= 3.1.13)
  bootsnap (= 1.4.6)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.4.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 1.0.0)
  byebug (= 11.1.3)
  capybara (= 3.32.2)
  faker (= 2.11.0)
  guard (= 2.16.2)
  guard-minitest (= 2.4.6)
  image_processing (= 1.9.3)
  jbuilder (= 2.10.0)
  listen (= 3.2.1)
  mini_magick (= 4.9.5)
  minitest (= 5.11.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.3.8)
  pg (= 1.2.3)
  puma (= 4.3.5)
  rails (= 6.0.3.4)
  rails-controller-testing (= 1.0.4)
  sass-rails (= 6.0.0)
  selenium-webdriver (= 3.142.7)
  spring (= 2.1.1)
  spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.1)
  turbolinks (= 5.2.1)
  web-console (= 4.0.2)
  webdrivers (= 4.3.0)
  webpacker (= 4.2.2)
  will_paginate (= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

#app/config/enviroments/development.rb

```
 Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
        'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Use this if developing on localhost.
  host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'http' }

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
end
```

This is the structure of my stylesheets

```
├── abstracts
│   ├── _function.scss
│   ├── _mixins.scss
│   └── _variables.scss
├── application.css
├── base
│   ├── _reset.scss
│   ├── _typography.scss
│   └── _utilities.scss
├── components
│   ├── _aside.scss
│   ├── _debug-info.scss
│   ├── _forms.scss
│   ├── _microposts.scss
│   └── _stats.scss
├── custom.scss
├── layouts
│   ├── _aside.scss
│   ├── _footer.scss
│   └── _header.scss
├── main.scss
└── page
    ├── account_activations.scss
    ├── microposts.scss
    ├── password_resets.scss
    ├── sessions.scss
    ├── static_pages.scss
    └── users.scss
```

And this is my applicaiton.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 * require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require main
 */
```

Comment: Are you running webpack?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using the asset pipeline.

Comment: `rm tmp/caching-dev.txt` (if this file exists)
.
Then run rails server with this command 

`DISABLE_SPRING=true rails s` 

If this resolves the issue then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.2 added Spring, which keeps the application in memory when you terminate it (to speed up start times), and Rails 5.2 added Bootsnap, which caches optimised code.

I'm using Rails 6.0.3.3 and trad css, and I see css changes applied immediately. Since you're using scss, I'd guess bootsnap is keeping compiled code hanging around.

Try `rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap-*`. Still a pain, but it'll let you know if Bootsnap's the cause.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. However, deleting the entire tmp/ folder fixes it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. 2 more suggestions to to try to diagnose it. 1. stop and re-start the server. 2. stop the server, call `spring stop`, then re-start the server.